# Definition of Inequality in modular arithematic

Tags: number-theory, inequality, modular-arithmetic

I am having trouble with the definition of inequalities modulo an integer. Given, $p \leq k$ and $i < p$, what exactly does

$$ i\leq k \mod p$$

mean? How is this inequality defined. I know for example that

$$i\equiv k \mod p$$ means $i-k= np$ for some integer $n$.

Comment: When $k$ is divided by $p$, the remainder is greater than or equal to $i$.

Comment: So can parenthesize it like $i \leq (k \mod p)$?

Comment: Sure, using the convention that $k \bmod p$ equals the remainder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that $i$ sets a lower bound for $k$ mod $p$.
As you are already given $i<p≤k$ there is no further relationship to determine.